# Kill a stubborn task from a C# winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, task, kill

I'm using a c# winform that opens a batch file.
I want to enable the user to press on a "stop" button in the winform and kill this task.
The problem is that the winform freezes itself until the batch file's run is fully completed.
So I used background worker (which enabled me to open a new thread that doesn't bother the winform's funcionality):

```
    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = (string)e.Argument;
        ExecuteTest(fileName);
    }
```

and noticed that I get to the "debug!" message but the command process doesn't die:

```
    private void tsbStopRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process prc1 = GetProcess("cmd");
        KillProcess(prc1);
    }

    private Process GetProcess(string processName) 
    {
        Process[] Prc = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        if (Prc.Length > 0)
            return Prc[0]; 
        else 
            return null; 
    }

    private void KillProcess(Process prc)
    {
        if (prc != null)
        {
            prc.Kill();  
            MessageBox.Show("debug!");
        }
    }
```

btw, if I open a command task and click on the stop button, the command task is killed...

How can I kill the background worker's command task from the stop button...??

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.

So what this means is that [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) might not be able to stop the process for some period of time either.

Changing you KillProcess method to wait for the exit code and see how long it takes to respond. You might need to alert the user that you are waiting for it to terminate while you are waiting for Kill to do it's work.

```
private void KillProcess(Process prc)
{
    if (prc != null)
    {
        prc.Kill(); 
        prc.WaitForExit(); //this has an [override][2] in which you can specify time
        MessageBox.Show("debug!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in memory the process that you stared. Do something like this:

```
private Process _commandProcess = null;

private void tsbStartRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _commandProcess = new Process();
    //Start process here.
}

private void tsbStopRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _commandProcess.Kill();
    MessageBox.Show("debug!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a custom build service I wrote. I created a property to keep track of the process.

`public Process CurrentProcess { get; set; }`

Then when you go to do the work in your background worker thread, you can initialize and start the process.

```
this.CurrentProcess = new Process();
//other initialization
this.CurrentProcess.Start()
```

Then, you should be able to access the property to kill the process. Depending on how you implement this, you may want to check if the CurrentProcess property is null, or maybe even if the background worker is running, before trying to kill the process.

```
this.CurrentProcess.Kill()
```